# problems and solutions for simple and harder optimal control theory?

Tags: reference-request, problem-solving, online-resources, optimal-control

I've been reading about calculus of variations and optimal control theory in Liberzon's "calculus of variations and optimal control theory".

He explains the theory quite well. However, he doesn't provide many practice problems with solutions. I'm not sure if I understand everything correctly, so I'd like to test it with practice problems.

**Do you know a good resource that contains lots of problems *including their solutions* of optimal control, both easy ones and more difficult ones?**

Answer (score 0):

If looking for example to practice, there are:

[Optimal Control: Pontriaguin and Dynamic Programming](http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~apnoco/Lectures2015/06-Optimal%20Control-Dynamic%20Programming.pdf)

[An introduction to optimal control problem](http://www.bcamath.org/documentos_public/courses/Course_Loheac.pdf)

[Lecture 10 — Optimal Control](http://www.control.lth.se/media/Education/EngineeringProgram/FRTN05/2014/lec10_2014eight.pdf)

[CDS 110b, R. M. Murray, Lecture 2 – LQR Control](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds110/wi06/lqr.pdf)

[CDS 110b: Lecture 2-1, Linear Quadratic Regulators](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds110/wi06/L2-1_LQR.pdf)

---

But if looking for practical problems, you will find them in academic papers rather than books. Here are a few examples:

**Wind Turbines:**

Islam, Kazi Shariful, et al. "Stability enhancement of DFIG wind turbine using LQR pitch control over rated wind speed." Industrial Electronics and Applications (ICIEA), 2016 IEEE 11th Conference on. IEEE, 2016.

**Industrial Electronics:**

Olalla, Carlos, et al. "Robust LQR control for PWM converters: An LMI approach." IEEE Transactions on industrial electronics 56.7 (2009): 2548-2558.

**Trajectory Tracking:**

Lin, Fengda, Zijian Lin, and Xiaohong Qiu. "LQR controller for car-like robot." Control Conference (CCC), 2016 35th Chinese. IEEE, 2016.

**Robotics:**

Mason, Sean, Ludovic Righetti, and Stefan Schaal. "Full dynamics LQR control of a humanoid robot: An experimental study on balancing and squatting." Humanoid Robots (Humanoids), 2014 14th IEEE-RAS International Conference on. IEEE, 2014.

Peng, Fang, et al. "Optimal balancing control of bipedal robots using reinforcement learning." Intelligent Control and Automation (WCICA), 2016 12th World Congress on. IEEE, 2016.

**Mechanics:**

Sam, Yahaya Md, Mohd Ruddin Hj Ab Ghani, and Nasarudin Ahmad. "LQR controller for active car suspension." TENCON 2000. Proceedings. Vol. 1. IEEE, 2000.